# Azure function- Method not found in azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I am using azure table  storage for saving data. And I want to create the method as azure function. When i locally debug, it's work fine. When add it in azure function, I got exception error

Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExists.

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            if (tableClient != null)
            {
                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(reference);
                table.CreateIfNotExists();
                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
                table.Execute(insertOperation);
                return true;
            }
```

And WindowsAzure.Storage package config,

```
<package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: did you create the storage in Azure? did you configure the storage connetionstring in app settings of the azure function?

Comment: yes, created. And it's working fine in local. And connection string hard coded, but not working.

Comment: Could you be deploying a v1 function app that you're building locally onto a v2 function app in the cloud? Even our earliest Storage extensions for v2 depended on Storage 9.3.1. My guess is that CreateIfNotExists() went away and became CreateIfNotExistsAsync().

Comment: Changed CreateIfNotExists() to CreateIfNotExistsAsync(), now got another error Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute.

Comment: table.Excute receives three parameters as described in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.execute?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTable_Execute_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableOperation_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_

Comment: Are you using .NET Core for the Azure function V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this problem (`MissingMethodException` from methods in `WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3`). It was being triggered by our class-library (using WindowsAzure.Storage) which was targeted at `net462`.

I checked the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package, and it had inside it versions for net45 and netstandard1.3. The net45 dll had methods taking CancellationTokens (like I was doing) but the methods in netstandard1.3 dll did not accept those CancellationTokens.

I still don't know how my class library (targeted at `net462`) was being used by unit tests targeted at `net7.0` - but the solution was easy - I just multitargeted my library to build for both `net462;net7.0`, and then immediately after that I could find the broken calls - and make different calls using `#if NET45_OR_GREATER`/`#else`/`#endif`.

So my suggestion is: update to the latest package, and if there's any chance that you have callers in different frameworks then multitarget your intermediate-libraries to provide different binaries for each framework

Answer (score 0):

Update the nuget to WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/ then publish your function it should work , make sure the connection string is configured in app settings.